# Uploading a text file in Flask and reading it in html

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to upload a simple text file and then display it in another URL in flask. However, I'm getting a blank output with **b"** as the only thing showing. Its just a regular text file with utf-8.

Here's the code -

```
def upload_source():
if request.method == 'POST':
    # check if the post request has the file part
    f = request.files['file']
    if f.filename == "":
        print("No file Name")
        return redirect(request.url)
    if not allowed_file(f.filename):
        print("File extension not allowed!")
        return redirect(request.url)
    else:
        full_filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], full_filename))
        print("File saved")
        content = f.read()
        return render_template('source.html', text=content)
```

and i'm including this in the **source html**

```
<p> {{ text }} </p>
```

I'm relatively new to python and flask and I appreciate your help here. Thank you!

Comment: did you check what you get with `f.read()` ? Maybe `f` is on the end of file and then `read()` will read nothing. OR get full path to saved file, open it and read it.

Comment: if I read your code correctly,  try adding a ```f.seek(0)``` after ```f.save(...)```.

Comment: @furas I was just getting a b" as output with the f.read, but adding the `f.seek(0)` worked! Thanks a lot @ewong! Now I have other problems to work around like the preceding b` and other formatting problems lol but hopefully i'll get past them :)

Comment: you get empty string because it had to read alll file to save it and it moved `pointer` to the end of file and then when you use `.read()` then it reads from the end of file and it has nothing to read. Using `seek(0)` you moves `pointer` to beginning of file and it can read again data.

Comment: `b""` means you have bytes and you have to use `.encode()` or `.encode(encoding)` to convert it to unicode string  - `b"hello".encode()` or `b"hello".encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your help on this and it's probably an encoding issue like you said. However, .encode() didn't work for me on this. I used something like this and it worked!  `content = f.read()
            content = str(content, 'utf-8')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters on this post, I could come up with a fix to this. Initially, I was getting a **b"** as the **only** output after using `only f.read()`.

When I used `f.seek(0)`, I got the output of my text file but with a lot of encoding and formatting errors, including a **new** preceding b` followed by my output.

But adding  `content = f.read()`
`content = str(content, 'utf-8')` fixed most of that aswell.

**So here goes the final solution**-

```
def upload_source():
if request.method == 'POST':
    # check if the post request has the file part
    f = request.files['file']
    if f.filename == "":
        print("No file Name")
        return redirect(request.url)
    if not allowed_file(f.filename):
        print("File extension not allowed!")
        return redirect(request.url)
    else:
        full_filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], full_filename))
        f.seek(0)
        print("File saved")
        content = f.read()
        content = str(content, 'utf-8')
        return render_template('source.html', text=content)
```

and don't forget the same old HTML -

```
<p> {{ text }} </p>
```

I hope this can help others as well. Thank you!